# how to add Authentication to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I already have a ready server on Asp.net WebApi. How can I add authorization to it? I looked through many articles, but everywhere a new project is created and the authorization method is selected there, but I did not find how to add to the existing one.

during creation was selected
[image]

And I need to add like this but to an existing project.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to implement Authorize attribute and decorate each of your API with the same. The authorize attribute gets hit before proceeding to your API logic and you can have your custom logic to check if the caller has the Authorization to access the API.

[Authorize attribute example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/thoughts-on-asp-net-mvc-authorization-and-security/)

Comment: it looks like it's not that

Comment: Are you looking for Authorization or Authentication? You mentioned Authorization in the question description

Comment: I am looking for how to add to an existing Authentication project